# Interpretation of ODE with Dirac delta input and initial conditions at $t=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta, initial-value-problems

Let's consider the following IVP:

$y'' + 2y' + 10 y = \delta(t)$

$y(0) = y'(0) = 0$

where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function. If I solve the IVP using the Laplace transform, I get $y(t) = \frac{1}{3} e^{-t} \sin 3 t $. However, this function does not satisfy the initial conditions, as $y'(0) = 1$.

How would you interpret this result?

Comment: If you limit the domain to $[0,\infty)$ (assumed condition for Laplace transform) and let $y(t<0)=0$, $y'(t)$ will have a finite jump: $y'(0) = 0$ and $y'(0^+) = 1$

Comment: This answer is correspond with $y'(0)=0$, your condition $y'(0)=1$ changes your answer.

Comment: @Dylan, as you say, the domain being $[0, \infty)$ is always assumed when using the Laplace transform. Hence, when we impose conditions on the derivatives ($y'$, $y''$, ...) at $t=0$, it is implicit that we are talking about $y'(0^+)$, $y''(0^+)$,... So, in my case, I'm solving the IVP considering $y'(0^+) = 0$, but the answer I end up with does not satisfy this condition.

Comment: I can't give you a more satisfactory answer, but basically the existence of the Dirac-Delta messes things up, so that the first derivative exhibits a "jump" $$ y'(0^+) - y'(0^-) = 1 $$ If you had instead started out with the I.C. $y'(0) = 1$, your solution would have $y'(0^+) = 2$, and so on. Also notice that you'd get the same solution if the equation was $$y'' + 2y' + 10y = 0, y(0)=0,y'(0)=1$$

Comment: Thanks, but I don't feel convinced. Let's look at your IVP, $y'' + 2 y' + 10 y = 0$,  $y(0) = 0$, $y'(0) = 1$. If we solve it using the Laplace transform, we assume, as always, that $y(t<0) = 0$. So we still have $y'(0^+) - y'(0^-) = 1$, even though there is no Dirac-Delta messing things up.